# Does the "offical" HAProxy ingress controller provide drain support?

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

We're exploring using the "offical" HARoxy ingress controller (https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/) and require traffic to continue to be sent to a pod that is in a terminating state, allowing state-full client<->back-end communications to complete before the pod terminates.  This is handled via "drain support" on JCMorais' HAProxy ingress controller (https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/).

We are unable to find any equivalent in the "official" ingress controller.  Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Based of this simple `grep` on the source code of each project:

```
haproxy-ingress % git grep -i drain | wc -l
36

kubernetes-ingress % git grep -i drain    
Binary file documentation/gen/doc-gen matches
```

I would say that `kubernetes-ingress` has no "drain" support included, as the word "drain" doesn't appear in the source code at all (it does in JCMorais' code).

If there is such a support in the official ingress controller, it does not go by the name "drain".